# Cant SSH to remote server trought VPN

Tags: server, ssh, network-manager, vpn

Currently am running Ubuntu 16.04 with installed and configured CiscoAnyConnect VPN. When I connect to VPN, I can't ssh to remote servers.   SSH is just standing and nothing is happening. I can ping and telnet on 22 to remote server. When i hit enter on successful telnet I get :

```
Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx ...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx .
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

Protocol mismatch.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Also happens when i want to open some HTTP page inside VPN. Telnet gives :

```
Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx ...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
Escape character is '^]'.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Connection closed by foreign host
```

On Ubuntu 15.10, I could `ssh` to remote server via Ethernet, but not Wireless interface. Can someone give me an explanation why is this happening ?